# how to get the .inf and driver file from a system

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, setup

How do I get the driver and setup info for HTC Fuze/Tilt from a Windows XP machine so I can install it on another XP machine? The HTC support site doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you mean a modem, have you tried the manufacturer's website? Thats alot easier then trying to sift through inf files

Comment: it's htc fuze/tilt and their support site doesn't work

Comment: Have you looked here? http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/windows-phone/f/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use Double Driver for that, it will back up the drivers and inf files.

http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm

Comment: it doesn't even show the printer driver